# Django: Localization Issue

Tags: django, localization

In my application, I have a dictionary of phrases that are used throughout of the application. This same dictionary is used to create PDFs and Excel Spreadsheets.

The dictionary looks like so:

```
GLOBAL_MRD_VOCAB = {
    'fiscal_year': _('Fiscal Year'),
    'region': _('Region / Focal Area'),
    'prepared_by': _('Preparer Name'),
    'review_cycle':_('Review Period'),
    ... snip ...
}
```

In the code to produce the PDF, I have:

```
fy = dashboard_v.fiscal_year
fy_label = GLOBAL_MRD_VOCAB['fiscal_year']

rg = dashboard_v.dashboard.region
rg_label = GLOBAL_MRD_VOCAB['region']

rc = dashboard_v.review_cycle
rc_label = GLOBAL_MRD_VOCAB['review_cycle']

pb = dashboard_v.prepared_by
pb_label = GLOBAL_MRD_VOCAB['prepared_by']
```

Now, when the PDF is produced, in the PDF, I don't see these labels but rather, I see:

```
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10106fdd0>
```

Can somebody help me with this? How do I get the properly translated labels?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Lazy translation"](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#lazy-translation)

> The result of a `ugettext_lazy()` call can be used wherever you would use a unicode string (an object with type `unicode`) in Python. If you try to use it where a bytestring (a `str` object) is expected, things will not work as expected, since a `ugettext_lazy()` object doesn't know how to convert itself to a bytestring. You can't use a unicode string inside a bytestring, either, so this is consistent with normal Python behavior.

...

> If you ever see output that looks like `"hello <django.utils.functional...>"`, you have tried to insert the result of `ugettext_lazy()` into a bytestring. That's a bug in your code.

Either pass it to `unicode()` to get the `unicode` from it, or don't use lazy translation.